# Android studio name tabs in activity

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an editText in which an user can choose a number between 2 and 8. For example, if user selected 5 then I want to show 5 new editTexts in the same activity. How can I do this? I found that is somehow possible with fragments, but I didn't find a very useful tutorial until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @kumud kala
Add a Linear Layout inside a Scrollview and then you can create a EditText programmatically like this.

```
LineLinearLayout llayout = findViewById(R.id.yourlinearlayout);
EditText yourEditText= new EditText(this);
yourEditText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
llayout.addView(yourEditText);
```

If you want more editTexts, you can initialize an EditText Array, and then loop through the number of edittexts

Comment: And how can I connect an editText to another one using java ? ( for example, editText2 to be down after editText1 )

Comment: As the parent is a LinearLayout you dont need to worry about that. just create edittexts programatically one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Take a ScrollView. In ScrollView you have a LinearLayout. Programatically if user enters n number then take loop upto n. In the loop create a new EditText prgramatically and add to the linearlayout by using myLayout.addView(myEditText).

Answer (score 0):

Place edittext & recyclerview in your activity_main.xml file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
                android:id="@+id/explore_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

then go its java class

```
      EditText edit_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit);

      edit_txt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
       public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
           if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

            exploreTopDownRecyler.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            exploreTopDownRecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
       exploreTopDownRecyler.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
            exploreTopDownRecyler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        exploreTopDownRecyler.setAdapter(ExploreTopDownAdapter.getInstance(context));
         topDownAdapter = ExploreTopDownAdapter.getInstance(context);
         topDownAdapter.addExploreItem(edit_txt.getText().toString());

         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
  });
```

Now make adapter class to add no of edittexts you filled:

```
  public class ExploreTopDownAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExploreTopDownAdapter.ExploreItemRowViewHolder> {

String TAG = ExploreTopDownAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
int count = 0;
private int mLastAnimatedItemPosition = -1;
private static Context context;
private static ExploreTopDownAdapter mInstance;


public ExploreTopDownAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
}

public static ExploreTopDownAdapter getInstance(Context context2) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new ExploreTopDownAdapter(context2);
    }
    context = context2;
    return mInstance;
}

public void addExploreItem(String item) {

    count = Integer.parseInt(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void animateItem(View view) {
}

@Override
public ExploreItemRowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    context= parent.getContext();
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlayoutforedittext, null, false);
    return new ExploreItemRowViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExploreItemRowViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return count;

}


public static class ExploreItemRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    EditText edittext;


    public ExploreItemRowViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        edittext = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    }

}
  }
```

itemlayoutforedittext.xml

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
 />
```