# update a textview in adapter from an activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to update a `TextView` in adapter (textViewNum) from the activity `SlotsActivity`  when i clicked on the button "btn"

How can i access to the `TextView` ??
keep in mind that the `listItems` isn't empty.

Here is my `Activity` code :

```
public class SlotsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Button btn;

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slots);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ....

    btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //i want to update the textview here
        }
    });

}
```

And here is my `Adapter` :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems ;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }
    ....

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ListItem listItem= listItems.get(position);
        //**I want to update this textView**
        holder.textViewNum.setText("N° slot : "+listItem.getNum()+"");
    }
      ....

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView textViewNum;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewNum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNum);
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Do you want to update the num for a specific position or the same for all the position?

Comment: Can you specify if you want to change the texts based on their position, or you want to change all the texts from your `recyclerView`?

Comment: @Tepits  I want to change the text based on the position

Comment: Do you have id or position to update?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `ViewHolder` as a child class of `SlotsActivity` and declare `TextView` variable in parent class.
Like

```
public class SlotsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapter adapter;
....
TextView txtView;
.....
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNum);
}}}
```

This way you can access and can change the `TextView` value.

Comment: the textview isn't from the current activity, i mean the textview is from another layout, so won't work

Comment: Then use `bundles` or `Intent.putExtra(value)` to store value on `btn` click and retrieve `bundles` in second activity

Answer (score 0):

**Try this idea**

```
// i is index of item u want to change text
View v = getViewByPosition(i,listView);
// then check if i is odd set background color with what u want
v.findViewById(R.id.text_view).text("what u want");


public View getViewByPosition(int position, RecyclerView listView) {
final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
final int lastListItemPosition =firstListItemPosition + 
listView.getChildCount() - 1;

if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition ) {
return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, 
listView.getChildAt(position), listView);
} else {
final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         listItems.add("Apple");
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //i want to update the textview here
    }
});
```

By doing this the value will be stored in the arraylist .

Hope you added the following line in your code.

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems,SlotsActivity.this);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307995/8316499

check this link

just pass your values in below method written in adapter

```
  public void addExploreItem(String item, Arraylist<String> textviewvalues) {

this.textviewvalues = textviewvalues
count = Integer.parseInt(item);
notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
```